# application deployed in server works in chrome but not in firefox and IE

Tags: java, spring, server, tomcat7

We've recently deployed an application in our tomcat server. It's working properly when we used Chrome, but when we've tried it in Firefox, it's not. The same goes for IE.

We've checked and found that when in Chrome, the status is 200.

[image: Image-1]

But in Firefox or IE, the status alternates from 302 to 200.

[image: Image-2]

Also, there are times when it works in those two browsers.
Here's some code snippets which might help :

```
private SecurityContext processSession(final HttpSession session) {
    LOG.info("SESSION ID: {}", session.getId());

    final int maxAppSessionTimeout = 28800;
    final String ssc = "SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT";
    // set context
    SecurityContext context = (SecurityContext) session.getAttribute(ssc);
    // set session timeout in seconds
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(maxAppSessionTimeout);

    return context;
}
```

We suspect that it is being caused by the method above since it sometimes returns null when in Firefox or IE. This method is being called by the code below :

```
public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest request,
        final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    User user = getUser();
    String userId = "";
    String uname = "";

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);

    SecurityContext context = null;
    String logURL = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
    String logParams = httpRequest.getQueryString();

    LOG.info("lOG URI: {}", logURL);
    LOG.info("lOG URI PARAMS: {}", logParams);

    if (session != null) {
        // validate and add new parameters in session
        context = processSession(session);
        // sanitize cookies
        processCookies(httpRequest, httpResponse);
        // commit
    }
    // anti x-frame
    // httpresponse.addHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN");
    httpResponse.addHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    httpResponse.addHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");

    try {
        if (user != null) {
            userId = user.getUid();
            uname = user.getUsername();

            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(userId)
                    && StringUtils.isNotBlank(uname)) {
                if (session.getAttribute("fullname") == null) {
                    // add user name in session
                    session.setAttribute("fullname", uname);
                }

                if (session.getAttribute("userId") == null) {
                    // add user nadme in session
                    session.setAttribute("userId", userId);
                }
            }

            initiateLogger(session, userId, request.getRemoteAddr(),
                    "userLogged");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception while getting employee information.", e);
    }

    System.out.println("context " + context);

    if ("/MTBBR/".equalsIgnoreCase(logURL) || context != null) {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    } else {
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP);
    }
}
```

Could you guys help us figure this out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post the code that is failing, along with any relevant server or javascript logs ?

Comment: Hi @PaulNUK. I've already edited my question. Sorry it took a while. Please see changes above. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you try in private browsing with Firefox and IE, does it change anything?

Comment: @KorayTugay we've tried it but the same thing happens.